# Best way to consume and test a Web Service

Tags: asp.net

I'm not sure if you put your web services in a seperate project but currently all our web services are in our WAP project under various folders....to me it's a royal mess.

anyway, besides unit testing, mocking, etc. I created a new Web Project.  I want to consume one of the other web project's service for testing purposes.

But I realize that when I add a project referene to that other web project, I start getting reference errors for stuff like 3rd party controls probably because the web.config in this test web project doesn't have some of the same keys.

Obviously this is the wrong way to go.  What is an easy way to utilize the service without having to refactor how we are storing the services at the moment physically?

Comment: To clarify, the source project is a Web Service project right?  or is it a plain old asp.net project?

Comment: Plain WAP project. The problem I have is I add the WAP project's dll to my test WAP project, but then I end up having to also add the same references that my WAP project (the one that has the .asmx) has or else it all falls apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your source project is a web service project, you can create a new asp.net web application project, right click and add a **Service Reference** to your service project.

From there, there are many ways to test the service.  You could make a page that would go through all the different service methods and generate a web page that shows you the results or have a page to allow you to put in inputs to test each service method.

Here's the MSDN page to get started with web services, they most likely have some good tutorials.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx

I also suggest investigating WCF services as another service option
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx

Of course, unit testing may be your best bet.  In visual studio you can add a unit test project to test the class of your web service and test the individual methods that way.

Comment: it only makes sense to me for services to be in a separate project anyway like anything else these days!

Answer (score 1):

Don't add it as a project reference,  add the web service as a web reference in order to consume it. For this to work though the service has to be deployed in some fashion (even if it's just on that box).

Another way is with VS2008 you can test web services this way (works great and I have VS2K8 Pro):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243399.aspx

For older versions here's an article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163830.aspx

Comment: what about a "service reference" if the .asmx is in that other web project?  Do I include that other WAP project into my solution that has my new test WAP project or can I reference it via just dll or something at the bare minimum?

Comment: you can use it to add a web reference.  After opening the add service reference just go to advanced button and add a web reference.  The reference is looking for a deployed service.  It will want the URL the web service is running at.

Comment: If you have VS 2008 Pro, you can test before deploying at all by using the link I provided above....

Answer (score 0):

If your current web application project is providing a service, you may want to migrate that service code to a **Web Service Project**.

Either extract the code / classes that are providing the service into a new project and decorate the methods that are providing the service as

```
[WebMethod()]
```

This way you could preserve your current codebase and just re-arrange the project and add some attributes to expose it as a service.

An alternative, would be to add a web service to your current web application.
It could live side by side with your web application, and you could create web methods to expose whatever serices you'd like.

Your test project could consume either of these services and test the individual methods.